# On click of every cell, google sheet shows the bar "Calculating Formulas"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I did some coding for Auditing, `onChange` function to record who did the change and when. I have now removed the trigger but still I noticed the whenever I click on any cell, the bar "Calculating Formulas" appear making my sheet very slow.
Please help.

Commented the `OnChange` call function, removed the trigger too.

Comment: Do you have any array formulas etc doing calculations on the whole sheet?

Comment: I have query functions running in the other tabs of the sheet. But it seems like even if I don't change anything, if I click in a cell the 'calculating formulas' bar starts appearing.